# Jenkins Installation

Tags: jenkins, centos

When I run the

```
wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/jenkins.repo https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat/jenkins.repo
```

It said use --no-check-certificate and hence I did. On the next step of installation while shooting the command

```
rpm --import https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat/jenkins.io.key
```

It throws the following error. I'm unable to figure out why as SSL expiration is not an issue.

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

    curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
    establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
    how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
    error: https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/jenkins.io.key: import read failed(2).
```

Answer (score 1):

These are the steps I took to resolve the issue:

update or reinstall ca-certificates

```
sudo yum update -y ca-certificates

sudo yum reinstall -y ca-certificates
```

You can also remove the previous jenkins repo from /etc/yum.repos.d and start the installation from scratch.

```
cd /etc/yum.repos.d/

rm jenkins.repo

sudo yum reinstall -y ca-certificates

sudo yum update -y ca-certificates

sudo wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/jenkins.repo https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat/jenkins.repo --no-check-certificate

sudo rpm --import https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat/jenkins.io.key

sudo yum upgrade

sudo yum install java-11-openjdk -y

sudo yum install jenkins
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your `ca-certificates` package. Its highly possible that its due for update and updating that package could solve this error.
It worked for me.